# Getting "/bin/bash: mkdirTensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimageshello: No such file or directory"

Tags: jupyter-notebook

[image: code]

`/bin/bash: mkdirTensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimageshello: No such file or directory`

Why this problem arrises?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the:

`IMAGES_PATH='Tensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimages'`

with:

`IMAGES_PATH='Tensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimages/'`

And the:

`!mkdir{'Tensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimages\\'+label}`

with:

`!mkdir {IMAGES_PATH + label}`

You forgot to put space after the `!mkdir` and it was executed as single command, which doesn't exist:

https://blog.dominodatalab.com/lesser-known-ways-of-using-notebooks/

Answer (score 0):

Replace the:
!mkdir{'Tensorflow/workspace/images/collectedimages\'+label}

with:
!mkdir {'Tensorflow\workspace\images\collectedimages\' + label}